# What if i write two classes with same name in one script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I have got one doubt "What if i write two classes with same name in one script" but with different functions. When we run this script, which class object will be created?

Comment: So what happened when you tried it? It's not the sort of thing I've ever done but I have a suspicion it would cause a large chunk of local space-time to collapse into a naked singularity. Do you _really_ want to waste our time informing you of things you could discover on your own with a little bit of effort? Is _that_ the best use of our time? :-)

Comment: Of course, the time I spent composing that witty retort above could probably have been used to answer the question three times over, but then I wouldn't have had as much fun :-)

Answer (score 2):

It will create an instance of the last defined class:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        return "a"

class A:
    def g(self):
        return "b"

a = A()

print a.f() # AttributeError
print a.g() # 'b'
```

Answer (score 2):

The reference to the first class is overwritten by the second class.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'A1'
...
>>> print A()
A1
>>>
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'A2'
...
>>> print A()
A2
>>> print A()
A2
```